# javascript function to modify innerHTML of a division tag

Tags: javascript, web

am new to coding in javascript and am presently working on a web page where i have some anchor tags in the left navigation bar and onclick of those links, i want to modify the content of a division named content!

the code im using is as follows

> for($i=0;$i".mysql_result($cat,$i,0)."
> ";
>   }

am grabbing the categories from my database and generating links for each of them.

> function phpload(clicked) {  
>     if(clicked.name=='php')     {       alert('hello');
>         document.getElementsByClassName('content').innerHTML='**hello
>   php**';
>                 }
>   
>   }

and my page i.e the content division is as follows!

```
> <section class="content">
> 
> </section>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` isn't returning an array? `document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerHTML='hello';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have more than one div you want to modify?  If not, you should use id and not class.  Class is for changing multiple elements at the same time.  Try something like this:

div:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Button:

```
<input type = "button" value = "Update PHP" onclick = "phpLoad()"/>
```

Script:

```
function phpLoad() {
   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "whatever you want";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1"> </div>
```

```
 var v = document.getElementById("div1");
            v.innerHTML = "Hello PHP";
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elementS.

Try `document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerHTML` or simply add an ID and use `document.getElementByID()`.